# Overriding classInstance.attribute[index]

Tags: python, class, overriding

if the way to override classInstance.attribute = value is

```
__setattr__()
```

and the method to override classInstance[index] is

```
__setitem__()
```

then how do I override classInstance.attribute[index]?

Comment: `classInstance.attribute` returns another object, suppose an instance of `A`, then if you need to apply index assignment to `A`, you override or add `__setitem__` inside class `A`...

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't get what you meant, could you elaborate more?